# Нужны ли вопросы о проверке корректности?

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов, причины-закрытия

Появился вот такой вопрос: [Правильно ли я конвертировал псевдокод в c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1246458/176217)

Задание явно учебное, автор усилия приложил - есть свой код. Но остаётся непонятным, какую пользу этот вопрос может принести другим участникам сообщества? Ну, кроме лишь возможности заработать репу на ответе.

Вопрос мог бы использовать метку [инспекция-кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0), но здесь же просто требование о проверке перевода из языка X в язык Y. Нет акцента на том, что можно что-то улучшить с точки зрения оптимальности алгоритма или т.п.

Моё мнение, что такой вопрос должен быть закрыт, как бесполезный для сообщества. Что скажете?

---

Или вот еще пример - [правильно ли я поставил счетчики перестановки и сравнений?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1248493) Просьба о проверке корректности и код, и больше ничего ..

Comment: Опять забота о коне сферическом, вместо конкретных людей

Comment: @avp сообщество - не сферический конь. Оно скорее конь многогранный. Хотя, конечно, при увеличении кол-ва граней до бесконечности получим ту же сферу.

Comment: А сообщество это что? Можно ли любого человека, который  зайдет сюда когда-то в будущем   (это метод предельного перехода) тоже относить к собществу? / imho уровень текущих посетителей различается порядка на два, тогда об интересах какой их части идет речь?

Comment: @avp в этом и смысл базы знаний - описывать "сферические" ситуации, полезные потенциально неограниченной аудитории

Comment: Основная задача всё же - дать удочку и научить ловить, а не выдать готовую рыбу

Comment: @andreymal, тогда этот вопрос потенциально полезен, хотя бы потому, что там надо правильно транслировать `repeat .. until` в `do { ... } while();`

Comment: @avp вот про это и должен быть отдельный вопрос тогда ;-)

Comment: @Kromster, imho вы слишком многого хотите от конкретных людей с их конкретными проблемами

Comment: @avp для кого-то и код проблема текстом выложить, прикладывают картинкой. Ну а чего? И так ведь прочитать можно, чего к автору придираться, да ещё и вопрос закрывать. Так что ли?

Comment: @avp пользуюсь SE уже почти 12 лет, и знаете ли, не вижу ценности в километровых простынях не относящегося к делу текста. Есть вопрос, как сделать А, не нужно для этого растекаться мыслью по древу и автобиографией ) Если вы аппелируете к тому, что в песка кода есть крупица золота, так не правильнее ли ее достать и показать под стеклом, а ведро выкинуть ..

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, да, вопросы с кодом картинками надо редакировать (наклонять ТС в комментариях)

Comment: @Kromster, я тут примерно так же давно. По большому счету, для меня ценность имеет наверное несколько сот тем. Остальное можно бы и удалить, но я не проецирую свои познания на всех потенциальных читателей и не считаю, что в первую очередь надо фокусироваться на входящих через гугл

Comment: @avp я тоже верю в естественный отбор (в духе, чтоиз 1000 вопросов, 100 будут неплохими, а 10 отличными). Но, мы с вами сами части той машины, что производит отбор (напрямую, и опосредовано).

Comment: @Kromster, на самом деле, мы опять скатились к обсуждению *предназначения этого сайта*. Вы считает, что он д.б. Базой Знаний, а я, что местом, где помогают **конкретным людям** в решении их сиюминутных проблем

Comment: @avp к сожалению, **решении их сиюминутных проблем** снижает качество ресурса. Вы сами обозначили выше, что код-картинкой это ниже *вашей* планки качества. Рад что хотя бы так )

Comment: @Kromster, мне пришла в голову парадоксальная мысль, что повысив уровень сайта достаточно высоко мы сделаем его никому не нужным. Т.е. тем, кто в состоянии воспользоваться знаниями такого уровня, это не нужно (они и так все это знают), а остальные не смогут, поскольку не соответствуют такому уровню. Вы хотели бы такой сайт?

Comment: @avp что тут спорить, золотые середины и компромисы нужны во всем )

Answer (score 1):

**Нет, не нужны** (в таком виде).

> Вопрос должен включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку (и минимальный код для её воспроизведения). Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Посудите сами, чем будут отличаться по сути 3-4 одинаковых копроса в данном стиле - *"Правильно ли я конвертировал псевдокод в c++ | `КОД1` `КОД2`"* .. Что за код, что он делает, зачем, какую проблему решает, а с чего автор взял что он некорректно конвертирован, а тестовые данные какие брать, и т.п. и т.д. (проблему XY тут еще вспомним).

---

**А в каком нужны?**

Ок, давайте разбираться. Для начала нужно поменять формулировку, чтобы вместо ожидаемого ответа Да/Нет был ответ по существу - надо обозначить и уточнить проблему - код не компилируется, не работает как надо, что с ним не так? Нужно добавить описание первоначальной проблемы. Далее, имея это, нужно задать вопрос о том, а правильный и псевдокод выбран, а правильный ли код написан. Нужно описание окружения и входных данных, ожидаемое поведение/результат. К этому моменту, скорее всего, вопрос будет клоном "как написать сортировку пузырьком" и его придется удалить, как дубликат (а еще лучше, не задавать вовсе, т.к. автор сам во всем разобрался).

---

Полезно напомнить, ruSO это не сайт делания домашек и работы за других, а база по сбору прикладных знаний и решений в форме конкрентых вопросов и ответов.

Comment: Кстати, еще одно соображение вспомнилось - практически любой вопрос на SE, подразумевающий ответ "Да" или "Нет" - нуждается в уточнении.

Answer (score 1):

> Моё мнение, что такой вопрос должен быть закрыт, как бесполезный для сообщества.

Только причины закрытия "бесполезный для сообщества" не существует. С такой формулировкой что угодно можно снести. Чтобы принять решение о закрытии надо все же разобраться, подпадает ли вопрос под наши критерии закрытия.

Вопрос, в данном случае, состоит из следующего:

1. Псевдокод на некотором алгоритмическом языке. Похожем на Pascal, но точно неизвестно, на каком именно. Что такое "list of sortable items"? Что такое "repeat"? Без точного понимания значения лексем невозможно понять логику работы формальной грамматики (если это вообще формальная грамматика).
2. Код на С++. Здесь по крайней мере что-то похожее на реальный код, но не видно объявлений всех символов (что такое "array"?)
3. Собственно вопрос "Правильно ли я переконвертировал?"

На мой взгляд, абсолютно подходит под причину закрытия "Непонятна суть вопроса". Автор должен был добавить информацию о том, что этот код должен делать, в чем именно он сомневается, если думает, что код может быть неправильным. Код должен быть законченным, чтобы его можно было собрать и запустить. Если используется алгоритмический язык, надо дать ссылку на описание грамматики.

Все ведет к тому, что автор попытался механически перевести код, после этого даже не пробовал его собирать и запускать, а сразу скопировал в вопрос на Stackoverflow. Большой привет авторам лозунгов типа "Задать вопрос не стыдно". Здесь важно понимать, что это абсолютно не вопрос полезности для Базы Знаний, такой вопрос, даже если все требования выше будут соблюдены,  все равно останется бесполезным. Никто не будет искать "Как перевести с непонятно чего на С++". Ну, кроме тех, кому нужно решение того же задания, разве что. Это вопрос контроля качества, причем самого элементарного, отсечения того, что и на форумах или в группах соцсетей, в общем то, не приветствуется.

Answer (score -1):

А мое мнение заключается в том, что этот сайт — это место, где помогают конкретным людям в решении их сиюминутных проблем и *тем самым* строят Базу Знаний. У нас есть некоторые стандартные правила о качестве, чтоб не превратить ресурс в помойку, но это явно не то, на чем надо зацикливаться.

Таким образом...

Такие вопросы являются онтопиком с точки зрения наших текущих правил (как я вижу, вы  можете поспорить, потому что правила — как любые людские законы — спорны). Закрывать их не стоит, под причину "не очень полезно для базы знаний, т.к. а кому оно надо?" можно подогнать все. Но выходит, что надо? ;)

Answer (score -2):

Возникла мысль, что всё же данный вопрос можно закрыть с причиной как учебное задание.

> Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности

Просто под заданием здесь надо понимать не результирующий код, а именно соответствие между входящим кодом и итоговым. Т.е. это своего рода работа, которую должен делать преподаватель, выдавший задание перевести из кода X в код Y.

А в чём действительно трудность вопроса так и не указано.

Answer (score -5):

Нормальный вопрос - чего придираться-то?

Comment: Вот зачем такие однострочные ответы публиковать, а? Особенно для вопросов с меткой [meta-tag:обсуждение]. Может нечто подобное и на упомянутый вопрос ответить? Ответ из одного слова "Нет".

Comment: А надо сочинение на 1000 слов выдать? А смысл?

Comment: Смысл, внезапно, в обосновании своей точки зрения. Вдвойне плохо, что такой "ответ" публикует модератор.

Comment: А я ставлю плюс!

Comment: @αλεχολυτ А это обоснованная точка зрения. Точка зрения: "не надо придираться", обоснование: "нормальный вопрос" (с точки зрения текущих правил и общего устройства SO).

Comment: @VictorVosMottor "не надо придираться" - призыв, "нормальный вопрос" - необоснованное утверждение. Чтобы стало обоснованным, нужны конкретный ссылки на правила или принятые ранее сообществом соглашения (ну хоть какие-нибудь рассуждения). Обоснованием это утверждение могло бы быть, если бы оно было самоочевидно, но оно таковым не является.

Comment: Давайте вот какой умозрительный эксперимент сделаем. Возьмите этот ответ и приложите его к ЛЮБОМУ обсуждению ЛЮБОГО вопроса на Мете. Ну как, ко всем подходит? ) Значит **этот ответ по сути ниочём**.